# How to Resolve Compilation Error in "tcolorbox.sty" File

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to make a simple colorbox using the package `tcolorbox` but receiving a compilation error by just including the `tcolorbox.sty` file.

Please consider the following code:

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{article}

% File Containing All the Control Settings
\usepackage{../../Style/mystyle}
\usepackage{../../Style/tcolorbox/tcolorbox}    ---> This line is giving compilation Error
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document} 

\end{document}
```

Compilation Error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@@qset was complete.
```

The Offending lines in the `tcolorbox.sty` file are:

```
parskip/.style={before={\par\pagebreak[0]\noindent},after={\par}},
noparskip/.style={before={\par\smallskip\pagebreak[0]\noindent},after={\par\smallskip}},
```

Please guide me how to resolve this error.

Comment: No problem because of the location of the Package {tcolorbox}.The compiler is able to locate the package. The compilation Error is because of a problem with the package file itself.

Answer (score 7):

`matrix` causes the error. Try this MWE (compiling with no errors), then delete the % and compile again.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,cmyk]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document} 
test

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5,colframe=red!75!black]
  My box.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My tikZ version is: Package: tikz 2008/02/13 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.27)

Comment: Thanks. I am re-installing the whole new texlive package, will let you know the result once the update is complete.